# Form with get value

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I have problem with my form

```
<form action="index.php?id=fakturysprzedaz" method='GET'>
```

After when I use some input for my form page address is: "index.php&get=value". I want to get adres some like this "index.php?id=fakturysprzedaz&get=value". Whatis wrong in my form header ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a hidden input field inside your `<form>`.

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='fakturysprzedaz' >
```